# System.net.Sockets.SocketException No Connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, iis, socketexception

I am a new member in a team project. I got the latest version of the solution, configured SQL Server and IIS, where they host the services (WCF). 
when I debug the solution I get this exception.

> System.net.Sockets.SocketException No Connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I tried this, and didn't work:

- Disable the firewall.
- Change the port in IIS.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can You verify, that the port, You want to connect, actually is active at all ?
There should be a listening application running on that port, please verify first..,.

Comment: the port in the web.config is 587, and the same in the IIS configuration. but when i use the [netstat -an | find "587"] command it doesn't appear.
am I doing it right?

Comment: Should be right. Do You have a) netstated without params and checked manually ? b) Do You have access to the remote machine in order to check, whether the IIS is running on port 587 ?c) Can You use wireshark or similar tools to detect the usage at that port ?

Comment: a) it still the same with the netstat without param
b)the IIS is running on my local machine
c)no i can't 

the 587 port is just for a special website in the IIS , how can i know wich port that IIS run on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to configure bindings, right-click on your website and go to 'Edit Bindings...'. You have to add a new site binding corresponding to net.tcp with default binding 808:*.